# Problems with Using Substance Designer Height Maps

Tags: materials, node-editor, displacement

I realize this question also deals with software other than Blender, but it's mostly a blender focused problem.

I am trying to figure out how to correctly set up displacement / height maps exported from Substance to Blender. Here is my node setup:

[image: Bad Material]

As you can see, the displacement is horrible. It's coming apart at the seams (black spots) and just generally looks horrible. This is what the material should look like:

[image: Target 1]
[image: Target 2]

So my question is the following:

What is the proper way to import and set up substance designer maps in Blender?

Is there an add-on that handles this automatically?

Is my node setup the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Go to User Preferences > Addons, search for and enable "Node Wrangler".

[image: NodeWrangler]

Once you have it enabled, when you are in the shading tab, with the Principled BSDF selected, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>. This will allow you to load a whole PBR set at once (navigate to the folder and select multiple files). It works fine with Substance Designer's default naming scheme, except I think it has trouble connecting the BaseColor. You can do this by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> with the BSDF selected to load a single image texture connected to the basecolor and then choose your image that way, or you can <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> duplicate one of the other image textures, load it that way.

[image: PBRSetup]

This shortcut method sets up the displacement for you, however how much of an effect it has in EEVEE is somewhat a topic of debate (as far as I know, it's not supposed to do something, but it does - but not always the best result). Instead, I sometimes prefer to run my displacement through a Bump Node. Either way you choose, also note that the default strength of 1 (on any of the bump/displacement/normal nodes) is often too high and gives undesirable results. I've sometimes needed to go as low as 0.1 before it looks right.

[image: PBRSetupAlt]

As a side note, make sure to make use of the Scale values of the Mapping node - I find many textures exported from Substance are scaled too large (1/4 tiled or so) and benefit by scaling by at least 2 or 4 on the X and Y.

Comment: Thanks for all that info. I didn't know that Node Wrangler could automatically set up your entire PBR texture set like that. Learn something new every day. :) Anyway, I actually think I pinpointed my displacement problem down to a lack of geometry. In order for the displacement to work correctly, I need a finely subdivided mesh (which my material preview ball isn't). But I really appreciate your thorough answer!

Comment: Make sure to use the experimental features and a subdivision surface using Levels to subdivide. It's adaptive (how far you are away from the camera) and non-destructive.